# open a excel file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: error]

I am using Windows and python 3.6.1

```
import xlrd
```

> workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\Users*******\Desktop\excela.xlsx")
>   sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

What is the error in the code?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your
way arround here. Also I suggest you check how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically how to create minimal, complete and verifiable examples. 
These guidelines will help you get better answers in the future. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

Backslash () is an escape code inside a double quoted string. 
Options:
- Change to "\" so it produces a single unescaped backslash. 
- Change to single quotes.
- Use forward slash (/) and let Python file handling translate to Windows conventions.

See this answer: [Windows path in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)